# Crud API post, put and delete

Tags: php, json, api, crud

I am trying this PHP-CRUD api, but how do I use it to post? Is it via URL like:

```
localhost/hris/api.php/employee_details/create?id=2&name=john
```

or I'm using it the wrong way?

Or the long way?

```
$url = 'http://localhost/hris/api.php/login';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'emp_id' => '2017-0007',
    'username' => 'jabril',
    'password' => 'Donor2017',
    'type' => 'admin'
);


$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I've also tried this

```
require('crud.php');

function call($method, $url, $data = false) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if ($data) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return curl_exec($ch);
}

$object = array('emp_id'=>'2017-0007','username'=>'jabril','password'=>'Donor2017','type'=>'');
$posting = call('POST', 'http://localhost/api.php/login',json_encode($object));
```

Comment: First verify if the api is a POST  or a GET  version. Then, you can check and see what happens? If there is an error, post it here. then we can see

Answer (score 0):

json_encode looks correct, are you facing some issues if any please share..

Comment: It should be in comments

Comment: yeah, I'm using this api https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api can I use the POST method on the url?

Comment: @varuog is right, you should learn this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer